# Jquery parse JSON data

Tags: jquery, json

I've got this JSON data coming back from my webservice.

How can I loop thru each line and append to a `<ul>`?

I've got the code below, but it does'nt seem to quite work. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('a#pop-video-link').click( function(e){
                // window.alert("test");
                var htm = "";
                // htm = $('ul.ad-thumb-list').html(htm);
                $("ul.ad-thumb-list li").remove();
                e.preventDefault();
                var src = $(this).attr('title');
                getResults(src);

             function getResults(str) {
               $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: 'data=' + str,
                        url: '/base/MyApi/MyPostFunction',
                        success: function(data){
                        var myData = JSON.parse(jsonString2);
                        var $grouplist = $('#groups');
                         $.each(myData, function() {
                          $('<li><a href="'+ this.url +'"/><img src="'+ this.src + '" class="image0"/></li>').appendTo($grouplist);
                         });
                        }
               });
                      }
             });
            }); 
             </script>
```

JSON Data trying to parse:

```
<value>[{"url":"/media/22.jpg","src":"/media/429.jpg"},{"url":"/media/44.jpg","src":"/media/55.jpg"},{"url":"/media/22.jpg","src":"/media/33.jpg"}]</value>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `single dimensional array of objects so data[0].id would have id` of first object and you also need to use length on it instead of count.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         var n = data[i];
         $('ul.ad-thumb-list').append('<li><a href="'+n.url+'"/><img src="'n.src+'" class="image0"/></li>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all your objects from data[0] with `$.each`

```
$.each(data[0], function(key, val) {
   $('<li><a href="'+ key +'"/><img src="'+ val +'" class="image0"/></li>')
        .appendTo('ul.ad-thumb-list');
});
```

see if this solves your problem.

Comment: thanks for the replies. I found that this seems to work ok:

var myData = JSON.parse(jsonString);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $grouplist = $('#groups');
    $.each(myData, function() {
        $('<li>' + this.url + '</li>').appendTo($grouplist);
    });
});